# Refresh Web Page after Converting base64 to image

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image, base64, memorystream

I have a base64 data and I want to convert it to Image in Asp.net. I use this Code

```
byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(imageData);
var path = Server.MapPath("~/ImageFolder/") +  "AAA.jpeg";
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, data); //(*)
```

when the code reach at line (*), Page Refresh, but I don't want to refresh.
what is solution for converting base64 to image and save in folder without page refreshing?

if i use `MemoryStream`, the Problem exist and page will refresh.

**UPDATE**

I have this codes on client sides

```
function ajaxCall(url, data, callBackFunction) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        data: data,
        success: function (response) {
            callBackFunction(response);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        },
    });
}
```

And

```
    ajaxCall('/Default/Save/', {
 final: _final, // Some boolean flag
        imageData: imgData, // Image Base64
    }, function (response) {
        $('#resultDiv').html(response)
    });
```

And in Server

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(bool final,string imageData)
    {
        var thumbHash = "";
        if (imageData.Length > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                imageData = imageData.Replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", String.Empty);
                byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(imageData);
                thumbHash = "123456789ABC";
   var path = Server.MapPath("~/ImageFolder/") +  "AAA.jpeg";
              
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, data); //(*)

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                thumbHash = "";
            }
        }

      
        if (final)
            return RedirectToAction("AddOne", "Cart", new { id = 12 });

      
        return Json( "Ahm" );
    }
```

Comment: I use Ajax. in view, I use Ajax call which is Async and in server Convert base64 to image will happen.

Comment: What do you do at the end of the above function call?  Is there possibly an error on the frontend that is the cause of the page to refresh?  Are you returning a JsonResult from your upload endpoint?  There are many questions I have, and would need some more context to provide any additional information.  Please, show how the endpoint is called (ajax, form post, etc), the server method, and what it does after uploading the image (return val, JsonResult, new View, etc).  If you provide a minimal reproducible example, i will test on my end.

Comment: I Update Question.

Comment: Does the image get saved to the file system?  Is the value of _final set to false for debugging?

Comment: How does the ajaxCall function get triggered?  Is it the result of clicking on something (ie. button, link, etc)?  Maybe the click event is causing the described behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem Solved**

Code has NOT any problem. after checking a lot, I found the Solution.
I only Uncheck 'Enable Browser Link' in Visual Studio and Problem Solved.
Thanks from Everybody Who Participate in this Question.

Comment: Thank you posting the solution.